# BackgroundTransferService does not update the UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My app downloads several images from the internet and shows progress of the overall download in one single progress bar. The problems is that the progress isn't being updated correctly when using a BackgroundTransferService.

This is what I have.

From my `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` I call download a list of the images urls that i want to download.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(MyDownloadList), null);
```

Then in the `wc_DownloadStringCompleted` I register a custom event `DownloadProgress` in my `DownloadManagerClass` which updated the progress bar in the UI `pbDownloadProgress`

Then I call the code which adds a new `BackgroundTransferRequest` and register the `TransferStatusChanged` and `TransferProgressChanged` (that resides in the `DownloadManagerClass`).

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{    
    var up = e.Result;

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => txtDownloadProgressText.Text = "Downloading");

        downloadManager.DownloadProgress += (src, args) =>
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("Updating progress to " + args.Progress ` 100);
           Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
           {
               if (pbDownloadProgress.IsIndeterminate)
               {
                   pbDownloadProgress.IsIndeterminate = false;
                   pbDownloadProgress.Minimum = 0;
                   pbDownloadProgress.Maximum = 100;
               }
               pbDownloadProgress.Value = args.Progress * 100;
           });
        };

        BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += (s, ev) =>
        {
            downloadManager.DownloadImages(up);
        };
        bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

And my `DownloadImages` method

```
internal void DownloadImages(String result)
{   
    List<String> URLs = ConvertStringToListUrls(result);

    var localFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (!localFile.DirectoryExists(TRANSFERS_DIRECTORY))
    {
        localFile.CreateDirectory(TRANSFERS_DIRECTORY);
    }

    numberDownloadedItems = 0;
    totalDownloadingItems = URLs.Count;
    foreach (String item in URLs)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Adding Uri:" + uri);
        Uri transferUri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(item), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        BackgroundTransferRequest transferRequest = new BackgroundTransferRequest(transferUri);
        transferRequest.Method = "GET";

        string downloadFile = transferFileName.Substring(transferFileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        Uri downloadUri = new Uri(TRANSFERS_DIRECTORY + "/" + downloadFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        transferRequest.DownloadLocation = downloadUri;

        transferRequest.TransferStatusChanged += new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(transfer_TransferStatusChanged);

        transferRequest.Tag = downloadFile;
        transferRequest.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowCellularAndBattery;            

        BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);
        Debug.WriteLine("Adding transferID: " + transferRequest.RequestId);
    }
}
```

Finally  my `transfer_TransferStatusChanged` method which mainly calls the `DownloadProgress` event when one file is completed.

```
void transfer_TransferProgressChanged(object sender, BackgroundTransferEventArgs e)
{
    if (transfer.TransferStatus == TransferStatus.Completed && (transfer.StatusCode == 200 || transfer.StatusCode == 206)) {
        if (RemoveTransferRequest(transfer.RequestId))
            if (DownloadProgress != null) DownloadProgress(this, new ProgressEventArgs(++numberDownloadedItems, totalDownloadingItems));                                
    }
}
```

Every step seems to be working fine but the problem is that on the output I get the debug messages indicating the progress that should be updated (like the ones below) but the progressbar itself remains unchanged.

```
Removing transferID: {05ea9c10-025f-4e90-bc55-e9d36424b5f0}
10:37:27 AM:200: Updating progress to 14.2857142857143
Removing transferID: {e92f79fe-dc99-48b3-b0b1-76d3f5cedd51}
10:37:27 AM:651: Updating progress to 21.4285714285714
Removing transferID: {f61c8c9e-aa41-4e2a-8906-fca06961e69e}
10:37:28 AM:30: Updating progress to 28.5714285714286
Removing transferID: {46abc1df-37e6-432a-9b55-0adb3a8a2235}
```

I already tried to remove the dispatcher use, to reorganize the code but I can't seem to get it to work.

PS: I removed some exception catching from the code to keep it simpler

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.downloadprogresseventargs.progress.aspx), `Progress` has a value between 0 and 100. If Progress >= 1 and you multiple it by 100, it will be greater than you progress bar `Maximum`.

Comment: Before I didn't multiply the value by 100, but I tried to change that thinking that it was the problem. Nevertheless just before setting values on the progress indicator I change its maximum value to 100.